# Dynamic sidebar layout in asp.net template

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I'm attempting to have a sidebar with a dynamic height and haven't yet managed to implement it so I'm asking for help now here - Most of the other posts I've looked up have a fixed height.

I'm using the basic asp.net layout. My solution so far overlaps my footer (which also has a dynamic height based on screen size).

My attempt so far looks like this: [image]

I've tried z-index but with no success

Using the basic asp.net template my outlayer looks like this:

```
//navbar top
<div class="container">
    @RenderBody()
    <footer> 
      //footer stuff here
    </footer>
</div>
```

My inner layout (rendered in @RenderBody()) then looks something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-2 bg-dark">
        <nav class="nav-sidebar">
          //nav stuff
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10">
     @RenderBody() //content
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
.nav-sidebar {
position: fixed;
padding: 8px 0;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
display: block;
width: 20%;
background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

I've seen solutions with a fixed height but I need my solution to be responsive and not with a fixed height. Thank you for any help!

Comment: how about set maxwidth and set height to auto?

Comment: sadly no diference!

Comment: The version matters a lot when it comes to Bootstrap and you haven't specified any. The code you post needs to be such that your actual issue can be reproduced easily without requiring answerers to write code for you. Here's a good page to read: [MCVE]